# How to send a string to the server and echo it back?

Tags: c, client-server

I am creating a program that asks a server for the current time. I want to send my name with the request and get the server to echo my name back with the time. Where do I insert my name?

A snippet of client code

```
    printf("Client is sending on IP address %s port: %d\n", servIP, servPort);

    /* Send time request to server */
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sendto(sockfd, buffer, (int)strlen(buffer) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, addrlen);
    printf("Request sent to server\n");
    /* Receive time request from server */
    recvfrom(sockfd, (char *) &current_time, (int) sizeof(current_time), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);

    /* Print the time received from the server */
    printf("\n The time received from the server:%s\n", ctime(&current_time));

    exit(0);
```

Snippet of server code

```
/** Message **/
printf("Server is listening on port: %d\n", PORT);
    printf("Waiting for client request...\n");
    printf("Press CTRL + C to exit\n");

    while(1) {
        addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        recvfrom(sockfd, buffer,BUFFSIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
        current_time = time(NULL);
        sendto(sockfd, (char *) &current_time, (int) sizeof(current_time), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, addrlen);
    }
    exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the time in the buffer, after the name.

Server:

```
printf("Server is listening on port: %d\n", PORT);
printf("Waiting for client request...\n");
printf("Press CTRL + C to exit\n");

while(1) {
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    recvfrom(sockfd, buffer,BUFFSIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
    current_time = time(NULL);
    memcpy(buffer + strlen(buffer) + 1, &current_time, sizeof(current_time));
    sendto(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1 + sizeof(current_time), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, addrlen);
}
exit(0);
```

The client puts the name in the buffer:

```
printf("Client is sending on IP address %s port: %d\n", servIP, servPort);

/* Send time request to server */
addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
strcpy(buffer, name);
sendto(sockfd, buffer, (int)strlen(buffer) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, addrlen);
printf("Request sent to server\n");
/* Receive time request from server */
recvfrom(sockfd, (char *) buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
/* Print the name received from the server */
printf("\n The name received from the server:%s\n", buffer);
memcpy(current_time, buffer + strlen(buffer) + 1, sizeof(current_time));
/* Print the time received from the server */
printf("\n The time received from the server:%s\n", ctime(&current_time));

exit(0);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I want to change the message that is sent to the server so that it includes a string(my name), and then get the server to send me the current time and also my name.

Comment: I thought the name was in `buffer`, which is what you're sending to the server in the `sendto()` line.

Comment: No I don't have a varible for my name yet

Comment: I updated the code to show copying the name into the buffer.

Comment: What does strcpy() and memcpy() do?

Comment: Are you kidding me? Those are basic functions that any C programmer should know. `strcpy()` is how you copy a string, and `memcpy()` copies any memory block.

Comment: I am pretty new to the C language. I appreciate your explanations

Comment: @Clancinio: "*I am pretty new to the C language*" perhaps learn/train the basics 1st, before starting to mess with such rather complex things like socket based client/server systems?